# Variation in shades of maple wood

Tags: wood

I went out and bought some hard maple for my desk. I've already glued the boards together to make the tabletop, but I noticed some variation in color between the boards. Two of them are somewhat dark, a few are white, and the other is half white half yellow. The white part was being covered by another board in the lumberyard, so I am assuming that maple yellows over time when exposed to UV light. This is not an issue for me, but I wanted to know if it is possible to even out the colors across the boards, and how. Will keeping the tabletop in direct sunlight help? Hopefully they can all have that nice golden-ish color.

Comment: The dark ones, surely you could have just flipped the boards over and used their (undoubtedly paler) undersides?

Comment: But the processing of the boards from their rough-sawn state should have *substantially* evened out the colour, as even a light planing of old wood can remove about 80% of aged colouring because it is so shallow (which is one of the reasons one has to be careful of sanding old furniture when doing restorations).

Comment: @Graphus I thought that would work as well, but the underside was just as dark. Will leave it out in the sun a bit and see what happens.

Comment: *"the underside was just as dark"* Interesting! There is of course variation in the colour of maple, as there is in all woods, but rarely is it more than a dark cream sort of colour. Anyway, did your subsequent surfacing of the boards take off a significant amount of the darkness from some or all of the boards?

Comment: Update: I used the desk unfinished and the color evened out. Recently decided to put a poly coat on and it looks great!

Comment: Good to hear an update. A year+ of light exposure will do a lot to even up the colouring in this sort of situation so it's great that you could be patient about it. Incidentally light woods all tend to darken (and perhaps go more towards yellow/tan/orange), while dark woods all tend to lighten or go duller, and sometimes both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After flattening the top/ removing glue, leave the top out in the sun for a couple of days before applying a finish. That should even out the color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: +1, is likely the correct Answer. But perhaps you could add some details on how not to put the panel in the sun, so as to minimise the chance of warping from uneven moisture loss?